# Read characters from file to end of line without using fread, fopen, fscanf, fgets

Tags: c

This is the file contents:

```
Hello 
how 
are 
you
```

I have to read until end of line for every line because I have to work on all of these lines individually. I cannot use `fread`, `fopen`, `fscanf`, `fgets`.

Comment: What is the reason not to use the functions listed?

Comment: because unfortunately they asked me explicitly like this. I should only use open, read etc.

Comment: Then you know what to use. What is the question then?

Comment: You can learn about `open` and `read` with [`man 2 open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [`man 2 read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

Comment: I managed to find a way with fscanf that allows me to read the single line but not being able to use it I would not know how to develop the algorithm in any other way

Comment: @Emanuele: `fscanf()` seems explicitly excluded.

Comment: Either read everything at once and then parse or read character-wise and check for newlines.

Comment: yes in fact i found a method only with this function that, unfortunately, I can't use

Answer (score 2):

You could reopen `stdin` with `freopen` and use `getc` to read bytes from the file.

If none of the stream functions from `<stdio.h>` are allowed, use the low level POSIX functions `open` and `read`. The manual pages are available online at [`man 2 open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [`man 2 read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (freopen("myfile.txt", "r", stdin) != NULL) {
        char buf[1000];
        int c;
        size_t n;
        for (n = 0; n < sizeof(buf) - 1; n++) {
            c = getc(stdin);   // or c = getchar();
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
            buf[n] = c;
        }
        buf[n] = '\0';
        // the file contents are in `buf`, handle these lines as appropriate
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: with getc could i control the \n ? how could I control it ?

Comment: `getc()` will read all bytes from the file, one at a time, including the newlines that are bytes with a value of `'\n'`.

Comment: it gives me problems in freopen, in particular in stdin and in reading the file

Comment: @Emanuele: sorry, the arguments for `fopen` were out of order.

Comment: I like the `freopen()` as it is not on the prohibited list.  I suspect piped input was the sought goal, but UV for this approach.

Comment: reopen stdin, excellent, I hope the OP understood this is not what we do in normal case ^^ UV too